# vim how to replace backslash \

Tags: vim

I would like to replace all backslash followed by a 'n' in vim. Like:
`s\\n\\g` 
[image: example]

Comment: Okay, so why don't you use a different separator?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams tried `s%\n%%g` the result is the same.

Comment: [This](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11086) answer on [Vi & Vim StackEx](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions) might be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:%s/\\n//g` will simply remove every instance of `\n`.

`:%s/\\n/(something else)/g` will replace every instance of `\n` with `(something else)`.

Answer (score 1):

Backslashes have always escaping function, so you have to use double backslashes.

For any other special character than a backslash you could use `:set nomagic` and when finished `:set magic` or even easier all in one step just add `\M` at the end e.g.  `:%s/a/b/\M`

But again each backslash has to be preceded with another backslash, to make your replace work use also a forward slash as a delimiter:
`s/\\n//\g`